# ASP.NET Server tag is not well formed error in a listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listview, client-server

The Following Image button works like a charm

```
             <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                <layouttemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </layouttemplate>
                <ItemTemplate> 
                  <asp:ImageButton onmouseover="javascript:show('Error1');"  ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

But now I would like to "make it work" for every record within the list view

So for record 1 it should be like

```
    <asp:ImageButton onmouseover="javascript:show('Error1');" 
    ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
```

for the second record

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover="javascript:show('Error2');" 
 ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
```

and so on...

Unfortunately some of the tries i made, like the following, produce the `Server tag is not well formed` error

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover="javascript:show('<%# "Error" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Counter") %>');" ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
```

So could you please point me, the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have any type of `<%` server side tag inside any server side control - i.e. anything with `runat="server"`.

This is untested and it's been a while since I've done any classic ASP.NET... but here goes!

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView_OnItemDataBound">
    <layouttemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </layouttemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note the `OnItemDataBound` attribute.

Now in your code:

```
protected void ListView_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) //You might want to change this
    {
        //this will be what ever you are binding... so the T in IEnumerable<T> that is the ListView.DataSource
        var someClassItem = e.Item.DataItem as SomeClass;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someClassItem.Counter))
        {
            ImageButton btnContainsError = e.Item.FindControl("btnContainsError") as ImageButton;
            btnContainsError.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "javascript:show('Error" + someClassItem.Counter + "')";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess i ll go with your way since i already use extended the ListView1_ItemDataBound handler... For Each btnError As ImageButton In e.Item.Controls.OfType(Of ImageButton)()
Next

Answer (score 1):

if you are using server side code tags (`<% %>`) inside an attribute, you need to wrap the attribute value in single quotes instead of double quotes.

Try changing your onmouseover attribute to this:

```
onmouseover='javascript:show("<%# "Error" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Counter") %>");'
```

Alternatively, you can create a method in your code behind and call it

```
onmouseover='javascript:show("<%# GetErrorText(Container.DataItem) %>");
```

And in your code behind:

```
protected string GetErrorText(object dataItem)
{
    return "Error" + (dataItem as MyObject).Counter;
}
```

Comment: Don't you now have nested double quotes?

Comment: Perhaps, but the inner set of double quotes are server-side quotes, while the outer set are client-side quotes (am I making sense?).  I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This one renders like onmouseover="javascript:show(&quot;&lt;%# &quot;Error&quot; + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, &quot;Label&quot;) %>&quot;);"

Comment: I haven't tested it, but from my experience, wrapping server tags in double quotes doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't put that concatenation inside of the <%# %> tags within the control.  What I usually do in this situation is create a public property on the form object and then call that property from within the control.  For Example put this on your form object on the code behind :

```
Public Function GetError(ByVal sVal As String) As String
    Return "Error " & sVal
End Function
```

And then you can put the following in your aspx page:

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover="javascript:show('<%# GetError(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Counter")) %>');" ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
<asp:ImageButton onmouseover='show(this.errorMessage);' errorMessage='<%# "Error" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Counter") %>' ID="btnContainsError" runat="server"/>
```